# data table with bootstrap modal(modal not working)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

I am using bootstrap data table with modal for displaying dynamic data from the database in blade template Laravel. Data are displaying properly. But the plus symbol which is missing in each row first column which is used to pop up a modal window containing row details. 
  There is no javascript error,or css missing. I cant able to post blade coding, so i am not able to post my code.

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand what ya want ))

In blade i'm using

```
<a href="{{ route('jobs.edit', $job->id) }}" class="flaticon-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#easyModal"></a>
```

And after click all data loading in modal, because bootstrap working with ajax

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you want..
but if you're using ajax and wanna load blade for fill in modal content, use this in your controller

```
echo view('path.to.blade', $yourData)->render();
```

if you wanna table responsive in your modal, add this in your js

```
var myTable = $("#myTable").DataTable({});
    myTable.responsive.recalc();
```

Comment: I have edited my question. please refer bootstrap data table with modal.   https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html

Comment: i never use that tutorial, i use another way to display datatable in modal.